# replace break line < br > with something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm working on a blog application where users could make posts through a text area.

my problem is when a user input contains a line break the value of the variable storing it (`txt`) includes the HTML tag `<br>`

For example:

> hello
>
> etc...

```html
const txt = "hello<br>etc...";
```

I'm filtering the blog to be posted line by line so I'm using that br as a delimiter in the split method.

```html
const myVar = txt.split(/(?:<br\s*\/?>)/);
```

after filtering it I would like that this line break would be performed without appearing as a part of the String.

example:

`const test = txt.replace("< br >" , "anAlternative");`

Is this possible?

Comment: Just do `txt.replace('<br>', 'anAlternative')` without `spit()`.

Comment: @tony19 what is the alternative to < br > if I want to make a break line without using it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a break line without using it"?